# Can pytest be made to fail if nothing is asserted?

Tags: python, pytest, assert

Today I had a failing test that happily succeeded, because I forgot a rather important line at the end:

```
assert actual == expected
```

I would like to have the machine catch this mistake in the future. Is there a way to make pytest detect if a test function does not assert anything, and consider this a test failure?

Of course, this needs to be a "global" configuration setting; annotating each test function with `@fail_if_nothing_is_asserted` would defeat the purpose.

Comment: So, you want to test the tests? I see a recursive problem coming up.

Comment: And what would happen with the exception raising testing that does not use the assert?

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel If the exception is expected, it is being tested for, so it's a kind of assert. If it's not expected, then it's obviously a test failure.

Comment: @KlausD. The tests are already being "tested", in the sense that they must be valid code, and produce green. This would just be a small additional sanity check. I have worked with a testing framework that did this out of the box, although I don't remember which it was.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the reasons why it really helps to write a failing test before writing the code to make the test pass.  It's that one little extra sanity check for your code.

Also, the first time your test passes without actually writing the code to make it pass is a nice double-take moment too.

Comment: Good point. Imagine, for argument's sake, that some hypothetical person would hypothetically, every now and then, write tests after writing the implementation. Any resemblance between this hypothetical person and any existing person, living or dead, is of course pure coincidence.

Comment: @Thomas I think I know this hypothetical person!  To be fair, I did actually have a quick poke around Pytest to see if it was possible, because I am very guilty of post-testing myself a lot of the time.