# Fail test if the assert statement is missing

Tags: python, testing, pytest, assert

A few tests in our codebase were missing `assert` e.g. `mock_http_request.call_args[1]['deadline'] == 5`, hence the tests weren't doing anything. Is there a way to configure py.test so it will fail/warn if there is no assert in the tests?

Comment: This has already been raised: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419754/can-pytest-be-made-to-fail-if-nothing-is-asserted?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa the idea is you shouldn't need to test the tests because it's general procedure.

Comment: The only thing i can recommend is either making it more known in procedure or by implementing a "finisher" of steps where you try to call a variable which has an assert in. if the variable doesn't exist it'll just error telling you to put an assert in